is anyone add statisctic columns successfully using add_stat function for tbl_continuous objects( not tbl_summary)?
is anyone add statisctic columns successfully using add_stat function for tbl_continuous objects( not tbl_summary)?
by using add_stat, we can custom statistic columns for tbl_summary() objects as follow:
e.g., return test statistic and p-value is separate columns
my_ttest3 <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  t.test(data[[variable]] ~ as.factor(data[[by]])) %>%
  broom::tidy() %>%
  select(statistic, p.value)
}

add_stat_ex3 <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_stat(fns = everything() ~ my_ttest3) %>%
  modify_header(
    list(
      statistic ~ "**t-statistic**",
      p.value ~ "**p-value**"
    )
  ) %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(
    list(
      statistic ~ style_sigfig,
      p.value ~ style_pvalue
    )
  )

however, this opertation fails when applying to tbl_continuous() objects as follow:
(aims to compute mean/sd of age on each level of each factor, and then add t and p.value )
add_stat_ex3 <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age,stage) %>%
  tbl_continuous(variable=stage,statistic = everything()~"{mean}({sd})") %>%
  add_stat(fns = everything() ~ my_ttest3) %>%
  modify_header(
    list(
      statistic ~ "**t-statistic**",
      p.value ~ "**p-value**"
    )
  ) 

error
"
There was an error for variable 'grade':
Error in data[[by]]:
! Can't extract column with by.
✖ Subscript by must be size 1, not 0.
There was an error for variable 'stage':
Error in data[[by]]:
! Can't extract column with by.
✖ Subscript by must be size 1, not 0.
Error:
"
PS: the add_p works fine
  add_stat_ex3 <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age,stage) %>%
  tbl_continuous(variable=age,statistic = everything()~"{mean}({sd})") %>%
  add_p() 

add stat columns using add_stat function for tbl_continuous objects( not tbl_summary)?
